# What's the name of this flower?

Tags: botany, species-identification

I photographed this flower in Central Europe. I looked in online databases but can't really identify the actual flower, since there are so many that look quite similar. Can you help me? What's the name of this flower?

[image]

Answer (score 13):

It looks like the common [*Geranium sylvaticum*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geranium_sylvaticum) (also called wood cranesbill or Mayflower), and it is at least a close relative (member of the [*Geranium*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geranium) genus). This plant is commonly found across Europe and in parts of Asia (see map below), and it is sometimes planted in gardens. It is a perennial herb that grows in many types of habitats (woods, meadows, road sides, mountain areas), and the flowers are most commonly violet to blue, but can also be white. [*Geranium pratense*](http://www.luontoportti.com/suomi/en/kukkakasvit/meadow-cranesbill) is very similar, but usually has more narrow leaf lobes and bent flower stalks. However, it might not be possible to separate these two species based on your picture.

There are also similar relatives found in North America (e.g. [*Geranium maculatum*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geranium_maculatum)) and Asia (e.g. [*Geranium himalayense*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geranium_himalayense)) and many hybrids of plants from within this genus are cultivated.

[image]
(picture from Swedish Wikipedia)

[image]
(distribution map from the Swedish Museum of Natural History: [Den virtuella floran](http://linnaeus.nrm.se/flora/welcome.html))

Comment: Superb example of a good answer to an ID question!

Comment: @Oreotrephes Thanks. The same species is just about to start flowering in my garden.

Answer (score 7):

My guess would be the meadow cranesbill (Geranium pratense), see this image (from [here](http://www.gartendatenbank.de/wiki/geranium-pratense), more images are available there):

[image: enter link description here]

The flower is quite common on meadows in europe, see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geranium_pratense).

Comment: This is certainly a possibility, and I have updated my answer to explain why I feel that *G. sylvaticum* is a better fit.

Comment: @fileunderwater I think we can be pretty sure that it is from the genus *Geranium* :-)